# Servlet For PHP in Netbeans

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, servlets

How do I create a servlet for PHP to work in a web application in Netbeans? Already using XAMPP. When ran at the moment server returns the whole page but does not execute it.

Comment: Servlets are a Java technology, not PHP. Real Java, not Javascript.